# Change accessor view on row selection

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am trying to change the accessor in a cell during some data loading : when the user selects the cell, I load data from a JSON service, and during this load I want to display a spinner as accessor. When loaded, the next view controller display what needed. I use this code but the accessor is not changed (even if I wait in the thread before returning from the method):

```
 UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    UIActivityIndicatorView *activityView = 
    [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    [activityView startAnimating];
    UIView *oldAccessorView = [cell accessoryView];
    [cell setAccessoryView:activityView];

    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject: indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

 MembersViewController *membersViewController = [[MembersViewController alloc] init];
            membersViewController.title = @"Members";

            // load the members, must be done in a separate thread and must change the cell accessor type to a spinner...
            JSONLoader *loader = [[JSONLoader alloc] init];
            NSString *membersURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/members/all.json", jug.apiURL];
            NSMutableArray *members = [loader getMembersFromURL:membersURL];
            membersViewController.members = members;
            [loader release];
            [members release];

            [self.navigationController pushViewController:membersViewController animated:YES];
            [membersViewController release];


 // restore old accessor view
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:5];

    [activityView stopAnimating];    
    [activityView release];
    [cell setAccessoryView:oldAccessorView];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not 100% sure I'm clear on the question. But the following might help:

1) It's not clear from this code that you are giving iOS the opportunity to update the display. It only does that at the end of the run loop. But from what I can make out all your code is running in the same pass as the run loop. If that diagnosis is right, then some judicious use of `[self performSelector: @selector(method:) withObject: nil afterDelay: 0.0]` will be needed.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7041261/how-to-display-uiactivityindicatorview-before-rotation-begins) might be helpful background. [The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364532/button-image-change-slow/7365036#7365036) to a different questions illustrates how to deploy the performSelector:withObject:afterDelay: technique.

2) Unless I'm missing something, you need to add `[oldAccessoryView retain]` before your `[cell setAccessoryView: activityView]` call. Then release it again after the subsequent `[cell setAccessoryView:oldAccessoryView]'. But maybe you are retaining the accessory view elsewhere.

Comment: OK thanks for this answer, it was not clear for me that iOS updates the display after the run loop. I will try to change my code according to your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

i agree with Matthew on point 1:
update on ui IS made at the end of the loop, so you have to do your REST call asynchronously.
For point 2:
given on what was in the accessory view, you may not need to save it.